# PL/SQL %rowtype variable declaration represents inner join

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my PL/SQL script, how do I declare JUSTIFIC_REC when it represents a join?

```
 SELECT * 
 INTO JUSTIFIC_REC
 FROM TABLE1 A  
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
 ON A.ID_JUSTIFIC = B.ID_JUSTIFIC ;
```

All I want is to insert into a TABLE3 a concatenated row:

```
 INSERT INTO MOF_OUTACCDTL_REQ VALUES(
    JUSTIFIC_rec.ENTRY_COMMENTS || '   ' || JUSTIFIC_rec.DESCRIPTION );
```

How should the declaration of JUSTIFIC_REC be like in the beginning of my script?

If it wasn't for the INNER JOIN , I would write something like:
     JUSTIFIC_rec   TABLE1%ROWTYPE;

Comment: Do you mean you want to select whole data set into variable (collection) or a single row ?

Comment: My problem is I dont know how to declare it. For example , if it was just the TABLE1 , I would declare   JUSTIFIC_rec     TABLE1%ROWTYPE;

Comment: Why are you using `*` if you only want to use two of the columns? And if you only want those for the concatenation, you could do that in the query too, so your result set has a single column expression and you can select that into a single string variable.

Comment: More information on what you're going to be doing with the data from this query would be helpful. I assume your query is something along the lines of `select trim(entry_comments || ' ' || description) from table1 a inner join table b on ...`?

Comment: I edited my question, hope I've made it clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question is itself in your question. You have to use the %row type
tow type attribute can be any of the below type:

```
rowtype_attribute :=
 {cursor_name | cursor_variable_name | table_name} % ROWTYPE
```

cursor_name:- 
An explicit cursor previously declared within the current scope.

cursor_variable_name:- 
A PL/SQL strongly typed cursor variable, previously declared within the current scope.

table_name:- 
A database table or view that must be accessible when the declaration is elaborated.

So code will looks like

```
    DECLARE
         CURSOR c1 IS
          SELECT *  FROM TABLE1 A  
     INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
     ON A.ID_JUSTIFIC = B.ID_JUSTIFIC ;
           justific_rec c1%ROWTYPE;


   BEGIN
      open c1;
loop
    fetch c1 into justific_rec;
    exit when c1%notfound;
     INSERT INTO MOF_OUTACCDTL_REQ VALUES(
JUSTIFIC_rec.ENTRY_COMMENTS || '   ' || JUSTIFIC_rec.DESCRIPTION );
end loop;
close c1;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: If my query not return fields, it return error in this part: "justific_rec c1%ROWTYPE;"

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly you can try with cursor rowtype like this (not sure if that is what you meant by declaring your variable type for the select with joins):

```
set serveroutput on;
declare

cursor cur is 
 SELECT ENTRY_COMMENTS, DESCRIPTION   
 FROM TABLE1 A  
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
 ON A.ID_JUSTIFIC = B.ID_JUSTIFIC ;

justific_rec cur%ROWTYPE;

begin

open cur;
loop
    fetch cur into justific_rec;
    exit when cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(justific_rec.entry_comments || ' ' || justific_rec.description);
end loop;
close cur;

end;
```

Comment: Explicit cursors are largely regarded as overhead but they have their uses, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BULK COLLECT INTO`

```
 SELECT * 
 BULK COLLECT INTO JUSTIFIC_REC
 FROM TABLE1 A  
 INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
 ON A.ID_JUSTIFIC = B.ID_JUSTIFIC ;
```

The `JUSTIFIC_REC` is needed to be TABLE type with appropriate columns

Comment: The OP is asking how to **define** a target variable with the appropriate structure, not how to populate it.

Comment: Hey @Dervis, how to define JUSTIFIC_REC?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're wanting to do is insert into a table based on a select statement, then there's no need for PL/SQL (by which I mean there's no need to open a cursor, fetch a row, process the row and then move on to the next row) - that's row-by-row aka slow-by-slow processing.

Instead, you can do this all in a single insert statement, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO mof_outaccdtl_rec (<column being inserted into>) -- please always list the columns being inserted into; this avoids issues with your code when someone adds a column to the table.
SELECT entry_comments || '   ' || description -- please alias your columns! How do we know which table each column came from?
FROM   table1 a
       inner join table2 b on a.id_justific = b.id_justific;
```

If you wanted to embed this insert statement in PL/SQL, all you need to do is add a begin/end around it, like so:

```
begin
  INSERT INTO mof_outaccdtl_rec (<column being inserted into>) -- please always list the columns being inserted into; this avoids issues with your code when someone adds a column to the table.
  SELECT entry_comments || '   ' || description -- please alias your columns! How do we know which table each column came from?
  FROM   table1 a
         inner join table2 b on a.id_justific = b.id_justific;
end;
/
```

This is the preferred solution when working with databases - think in sets (where possible) not procedurally (aka row-by-row processing). It is easier to maintain, the code is simpler to read and write, and it'll be more performant since you're not having to switch between PL/SQL and SQL several times with each row.

Context switching is bad for performance - think in terms of a bath full of water - is it quicker to empty the bath with a spoon (row-by-row processing), with a jug (batched rows - by - batched rows) or by pulling the plug (set-based)?

Comment: No, I have to do it in a pl/sql script!

Comment: You can plonk the insert into PL/SQL! Just put a begin/end around it!

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a PL/SQL script? If it's to learn how to loop around a cursor (e.g. for school-work), then it's just about ok to stick with the answer you already accepted, but **never** do it when you are programming professionally. I would reject the row-by-row method if I ever came across it in a code review!

Comment: In my insert statement i have lots of columns from different tables, so I can not do that. I keep having problem with this, even though the above offered solutions seemed right to me at  first glance !

Comment: So, don't you have a select statement that pulls together all the columns and rows you're after?

Comment: No, i have cursors, many select-into statements and nested loops that already run fine when i commit insert into my table, but with this field i have issue, because i want to join 2 tables and i still can't do it in PL/SQL .

Comment: I suggest you create a new question that contains a rerunnable test case - e.g. a  script (ideally something that could be run on https://dbfiddle.uk or https://livesql.oracle.com) containing create table statements, insert statements to populate the tables with sample data and what you're expecting to see at the end of running your PL/SQL. That way, we should be able to help you better. Make sure your test case accurately reflects what it is you're trying to do, but make it as small as you can so we're not bogged down by irrelevant information.